# What is a prescriptive way for managing the permissions for mounted volumes in Alpine-based Docker?

Tags: permissions, mount, docker, alpine-linux

When you build an image you can assign ownership (`chown`) and change permissions (`chmod`) of paths within the image. However, when a volume is mounted from either the host or another container the permissions for that volume are present, potentially introducing a user/group unknown to the container it is mounted within.

I'm interested in a prescriptive method (if one exists) to handle permissions for users under an Alpine Docker image for both host mounted and container mounted volumes.

The two possible options that I can think of are:

1. Use the same user and group between containers and mounted volumes.
2. Use ACLs to control the permissions.

Is there a recommended approach for addressing permission issues for mounted volumes, especially when the uid/gid of the owners does not match with users/groups inside of a container? E.g.

Within my Alpine Docker image my `www-data` user has a uid/gid of 82 (see: [nginx www-data user id](http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/nginx-initscripts/nginx-initscripts.pre-install?h=v3.3.2)), if I mount a volume from another container or the host where a user with the uid `1001` and gid `1001` owns the volume, how do I deal with the disparity in ownership and permissions?

---

**NB:** Some application frameworks (e.g. [Symfony](http://symfony.com/)) recommend using something like `setfacl` [[1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup)] to manage permissions, but this does not seem to be possible under an Alpine Docker image with AUFS because the operation is"not supported".

Is using ACLs an anti-pattern in Docker?

Answer (score 3):

> **NB:** [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) has the following question: [What is the best way to manage permissions for docker shared volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes) which is similar to the above and numerous answers, with the prevailing answer being this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27021154/657674).

From experimentation and reading numerous sources looking for a prescriptive answer or common pattern I've identified the following:

**When running Docker-outside-of-Docker (DooD) host data volumes are mounted from the underlying host.** I remember stumbling across some mention of this in a blog post, but for the life of me I can't find it now (If/when I do, I'll update this answer). The long and short of it is this: when you're running Docker through a shared `docker.sock` within a container, Docker is going to attempt to mount volumes from the *underlying* host. If you mount volume(s) from another container you don't have this issue.

**Assigning permissions and ownership.** The issue I noted above (with `setfacl` not working) appears to have been a user issue. I must have been trying to run it under the permissions of the non-root user or against a directory that my user did not have ownership of. In order to get around ownership issues you can use a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script that will either `chown` or `setfacl` as the root user before executing the command as the user for the image. As of yet I've identified two feasible options to handle ownership and permissions issues:

- Use `sudo` to change ownership or set access control lists.
- Allow your container to run using the `root` user and then step down to another user to execute the command using [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) or [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec).

---

I took to combining the two observations above for my self-prescriptive approach, so...

1. Whenever mounting a host volume in a Docker container that also shares the `docker.sock` with the host, it is advised that the directories should match. For example, if the volume mount in the Dockerfile is declared as `/var/data` then mount `/var/data` from the host (e.g. `-v /var/data:/var/data`). This is especially if you have files or directories under `/var/data` that you will want to mount from within the container in a new container.
2. Be proactive about permissions, always include a `docker-entrypoint.sh` file that at the very least updates the ownership or access control for a mounted directory.